# Add some calculation to CLLocationDistance

Tags: swift5, cllocation, xcode12, cllocationdistance

Here is my problem I can print in console double value (aka the distance) but I can't take a double and add the distance in a table view for exemple.

```
if previousLocation == nil {
            previousLocation = locations.first
        } else {
            guard let latest = locations.first else { return }
            let distanceInMeters = previousLocation?.distance(from: latest) ?? 0
            print("Distance in meters: \(distanceInMeters)")
            guard var unwrappedPaceNumber = paceNumber.first else { return }
            
            let total = unwrappedPaceNumber += "\(distanceInMeters)"
            paceNumber[0] = "\(total)"
            tableView.reloadData()
            
            previousLocation = latest
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean you "can't take a double and add the distance in a table view"? What error did you get? How does the actual result differ from your expectation?

Comment: I'have a fake array with fake data of type String (paceNumber) ,  When I want to add distance in meters to the first fake dat in the fake array. Compiler say total is of type ().  In documentation they say CLlocationDistance is of type Double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up like that
If this can help

```
 if previousLocation == nil {
            previousLocation = locations.first
        } else {
            guard let latest = locations.first else { return }
            let distanceInMeters = previousLocation?.distance(from: latest) ?? 0
            var distanceRounded = distanceInMeters.rounded()
            print("Distance in meters: \(distanceRounded)")
            let unwrappedPaceNumber = paceNumber[0]
            distanceRounded += Double(unwrappedPaceNumber)!
            paceNumber[0] = "\(distanceRounded)"
            print(paceNumber[0])
            tableView.reloadData()

            previousLocation = latest
        }
```